# Working with the file name

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, 2016, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am fairly new to SharePoint and also working with a German version, so please excuse and correct any wrong terminology.

On SP2016, I have an image library and have added a calculated column. I am looking for a formula that gives me the filename (e.g. "AnyImage.gif"), just as =[AnyColumnName] would give me what is in that column. I was hoping naively that =[NAME] would do that, but it produces an error.

Can someone help me in this particular case, or direct me to a guide how to access the "special columns" of a list in general?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known limitation of SharePoint. We cannot use file name in calculated column formula.

There is a SharePoint UserVoice for this. You can vote here: [Use filename in calculated field](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/36029680-use-filename-in-calculated-field)

**Workaround**:

1. Create a new text field & populate its value using workflow on item creation/update. Hide this field from property forms.
2. Use workflow to updated the Title field based on the filename. Then use Title field in the calculated column formula.